# Is there a way to initiate Facebook live streaming from android like Youtube does?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent, facebook-live-api

So I have a requirement where a user clicks on a CTA in my app and I should take the user to Facebook live streaming, similar to youtube(In Youtube we have a Mobile Live Intent to directly take the user to the live streaming activity in the Youtube App).

I tried the Facebook Live Video Api in development mode and its working, but it is mentioned in their Platform policy [Facebook privacy policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) that "Don’t use the API to stream directly from a mobile phone or tablet camera to Facebook.". So my question is

(i)  - Will they block my application when I move to production, because it is mentioned clearly to not use Live Video Api from mobile device?

(ii) - Do they have any intent like Youtube has for live streaming or any other way of achieving this?

Thanks.